# Not Kerberized Kafka broker connection to Kerberized Zookeeper

Tags: apache-kafka, cluster-computing, apache-zookeeper, kerberos, ambari

I couldn't find any info about this issue, so I'd be glad if someone could help me on this.

I have a **Kerberized cluster** with services such as *Hbase, MapReduce, HDFS, Zookeeper*,... all kerberized and working.

Let's imagine I want to add some **kafka brokers** to the cluster, but I do **not** want to **Kerberize Kafka**, since a shot in the testicles makes me feel better than the idea of a kerberized Kafka.

I don't know if I'm missing something, some parameter... probably I am.. but can the zookeeper be told that also has to accept `PLAINTEXT` petitions for some nodes, or for some specific directories, such as kafka in the example:

> zookeeper:2181/**kafka**

---

Resuming, the question is:

- Is there any option to include a non kerberized Kafka Broker and make it work against the already kerberized Zookeeper in the cluster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need configuration like:

```
[zookeeper] <----- SASL ----> [kafka] <----- non-authenticated request ---> [clients]
```

then yes, it's possible. You need just to

1. Create principal (with keytabs) for brokers that will be used to communicate with Zookeeper.
2. Configure Zookeeper ACLs, setting `cdrwa` access to the node `zookeeper:2181/kafka` to that user
3. Copy the keytab to brokers and configure Kafka jaas file like this:

   `ZookeeperClient {
       com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required
       useKeyTab=true
       storeKey=true
       keyTab="/path/to/keytab"
       principal="user@REALM";
   };`

Then, set `zookeeper.set.acl=true` in Kafka configuration, but do not set any `authorizer.class.name` (this would enable authentication for Kafka consumers and producers)

Comment: Thanks Mariusz! I will try as soon as possible. Just a question: for this configuration to be valid, is it necessary to change zookeeper default node? I mean, the zookeeper:2181 (default one) would still be valid, right? I mean, this non Kerberos Kafka won't "disturb" other Kerberos Kafka that also connects to zookeeper:2181, right? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: If you want to use 2 (or more) Kafkas on one zookeeper, you should first create a root node for each and pass connection string with the node, for example: `zookeeper:2181/kafka1`, `zookeeper:2181/kafka2`. If you follow that way, different clusters will be separated completely.

Comment: Mariusz, thanks a lot. I finally could make a non kerberos Broker work with a kerberized zookeeper. (I made a wrong statement in the last comment, didn't mean to say another Kafka, but another process that connects to zookeeper, but I tested that this config didn't harm any other service). Anyway, there's a last question that intrigues me... the 0.9 consumer still connects to zookeeper in order to consume messages...how can It be working, without using an specific principal? Or does Kafka use the principal that connects (Client) to the zookeeper when you use the console-consumer?? BIG THANKS!!

Comment: it's strange - if you use old-consumer (with offsets in ZK) without authenticaion in ZK and in the same ZK has secured Kafka nodes - it shouldn't work :-)

Comment: totally my fault, I knew there was something strange about that... I was running ubuntu's default zookeeper instead, had to reset multiple times for network issues and didn't remember to launch my kerberized zookeeper when running the consumer and producers. Ouch!!

Big thanks again!